# Advertencia en PHPMyAdmin después de actualizar

Tags: mysql

Hoy he actualizado PHPMyAdmin de la versión 5.1.1 a la versión 5.1.2 y me ha saltado una advertencia con el siguiente mensaje: [Undefined array key "hide_connection_errors"].

Si alguien sabe como solucionarlo que comparta la solución, muchas gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esta pregunta no se trata de MySQL, si no de PHPMyAdmin. Tu versión de MariaDB es 10.4.21

Comment: Hola @aeportugal, ha sido buena observación y por supuesto que era error mío, con lo que he procedido a modificar el título y la descripción para que no de lugar a dudas, muchas gracias. Un saludo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He buscado un poco por internet a ver si le había pasado a alguien más y por lo visto es un bug que ya había sucedido antes en la versión 4.9.9.

Os comparto la solución que he encontrado en github y que a mí me ha funcionado:
https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/pull/17304/commits/b2fa57efa66e23de2b0c1bce63ae5dd9fdb3f262

He seguido las instrucciones que había, abriendo el archivo DbiMysqli.php en la siguiente ruta -> C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin\libraries\classes\Dbal\DbiMysqli.php

He sustituido esta línea -> if ($server['hide_connection_errors']) {

Por esta otra -> if (array_key_exists('hide_connection_errors',$server) && $server['hide_connection_errors']) {

He abierto de nuevo http://localhost/phpmyadmin/ y ya no estaba la advertencia.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero que os sirva de ayuda y si encontrais otra solución, compartidla por favor, muchas gracias.
Un saludo.